# How do I make timeSeries plot display time in local timezone?

Tags: r, plot, timezone

I'm using `timeSeries` package for manipulating and plotting time series.  I can create `timeSeries` object using GMT times, then, by setting `finCenter` property to "NewYork" I make it print times in New York local time zone.  `plot()` function also takes `FinCenter` argument, and one would think that by setting it you would get local times plotted on x axis. But it doesn't work for me, it still displays in GMT, no matter what I do.

```
a <- Sys.timeDate() + 1:5
a
# NewYork
# [1] [2015-09-29 21:54:50] [2015-09-29 21:54:51] [2015-09-29 21:54:52]
# [4] [2015-09-29 21:54:53] [2015-09-29 21:54:54]
at <- timeSeries(1:5, a)
at
# NewYork
#                     TS.1
# 2015-09-29 21:54:50    1
# 2015-09-29 21:54:51    2
# 2015-09-29 21:54:52    3
# 2015-09-29 21:54:53    4
# 2015-09-29 21:54:54    5
plot(at)
plot(at, FinCenter = "NewYork")
```

Both `plot` functions render the same x axis labels, in GMT. Anybody knows how to fix it?

Comment: `plot(at, at="chic")` seems to give the right times, though there doesn't seem to be a flexible way to deal with timezone changes properly - see this document for more info: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeSeries/vignettes/timeSeriesPlot.pdf

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  I've seen this document before, I didn't find anything addressing my problem.  I wish FinCenter setting would work for plot, but will get by by using "chic" for now.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: The other option is to plot without axes and then add them in manually - `plot(at,axes=FALSE); axis(1, at=axTicks(1), labels=format(time(at),"%H:%M:%S"));axis(2, at=axTicks(2));box()`

Comment: @thelatemail - thank you, it works too, but I had to adjust it for my actual use case.  I have a timeseries of thousands of observations, so I ended up with this: `a = pretty(at); finCenter(a)<-"NewYork"; axis(1, at=as.POSIXct(a), labels=format(a,"%H:%M"))`